# How to generate invoices for the application fees with Stripe direct charges?

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm launching a marketplace where some professionals offer their services and customers can book and pay them online. I take  percentage fees in the process and I use stripe direct charges for that. So when a customer proceed to a stripe payment though my website the professional (the connected account) gets paid and automatically pays me (the platform account) the application fees percentage that I set.

I've searched on stripe website and couldn't find an answer: Is it possible to generate automatically some invoices from my platform account to the connected account that would be related to the application fees ?

For example if the professional's price is 10$ and the application fees that I set is 10% how could I generate the 1$ invoice to the professional ?

I only found how to build or generate invoices for connected account to their customers but not invoices involving the platform account and the connected account.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like what you are looking for is an `application_fee`[1] .  As the diagram[2] displays, the professional (Connected account) charges the customer directly but your application fee is collected and deposited in your account during the funds flow of the Connected account.

This does not provide any invoice to the professional since the `application_fee` is sent to your account at the same time as the remaining funds are transferred to the Connected account.  This process allows you to have a set percentage based application fee you charge the professionals on your marketplace.

The `application_fee` approach is the recommended way of collection a fee as part of a direct charge.  This will not generate an invoice to your Connected accounts automatically but you could always generate one of your own (outside of Stripe) as a record of the fee for those accounts.

---

1. https://stripe.com/docs/connect/direct-charges#collecting-fees
2. https://stripe.com/docs/connect/direct-charges#flow-of-funds-with-fees

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What I understood from the diagram is that the application_fee is sent to me (or collected by me) automatically from the professional (connected account) which is perfect legally for me because my customer is only the professional and it's specified that way in the terms of use of my website. I'm a bit surprised and disappointed that stripe doesn't propose an invoice generation option for application_fee since all the market places that work the same way as mine need to generate invoices for that. I'll generate it on my own if I have no choice.

Comment: I hope Stripe will implement that feature. It would be very pratical.